# How to retain data read from files in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem, that is I read data from a text file like this:

```
open(DATA1, "<test.txt") or die $!;
```

I would like to use DATA1 in more than one places (say I will loop through it in two subs). But I find that it only behaves right in the first sub, while in the second, there is nothing there. I wonder if there's a way to retain what I read from the file and use it in multiple places. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rewind your file pointer to the beginning of the file with the `seek` function.  Seek to 0 to return the file handle position to the beginning of the file, and you'll be able to read it again.

Comment: it works fine with seek function, but my puzzle is: is this a good practice to apply to? Because there would be lots of seek #,#,# in each sub before it returns.

Comment: You could also seek the file handle before passing it to the subs.  That would make more sense to me -reuse of the file handle isn't really part of the subs, it's more part of the containing code to prepare the subs' parameters for them.

Reusing file handles is an OK practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lexical file handle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# ...

open my $fh, '<', 'test.txt';
```

Then you can pass it as a scalar to any of your functions to be read just like you would the typeglob.

```
while (<$fh>) {
```